# Как соединить Contact form 7 и Cloudpayments?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Подвязал к форме плагина Contact form 7 на сайте Wordpress платежку Cloudpayments. Как сделать, чтобы форма Contact form 7 отправлялась после успешной оплаты? Сейчас при заполнении полей формы и нажатии на кнопку отправить - форма отправляется, после этого открывается Cloudpayments. Нужно сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отправки формы, форма не отправлялась, а открывалась платежка, а уже потом, происходила отправка формы, после оплаты.

Вот скрипт, обрабатывающий платежку

```
const payPopup = () => {
  var widget = new cp.CloudPayments();
  widget.pay('auth', // или 'charge'
      { //options
          publicId: publicId, //id из личного кабинета
          description: globalText, //назначение
          amount: globalAmount, //сумма
          currency: 'RUB', //валюта
          accountId: nameUser.value, //идентификатор плательщика (необязательно)
          //invoiceId: '1234567', //номер заказа  (необязательно)
          //email: 'user@example.com', //email плательщика (необязательно)
          skin: "mini", //дизайн виджета (необязательно)
          autoClose: 3, //время в секундах до авто-закрытия виджета (необязательный)
          data: {
              myProp: 'myProp value'
          },
          configuration: {
              common: {
                  successRedirectUrl: "/success-pay", // адреса для перенаправления
                  failRedirectUrl: "/fail-pay"        // при оплате по Tinkoff Pay
              }
          },
      },
      {
          onSuccess: function () { // success
              //действие при успешной оплате
          },
          onFail: function (reason, options) { // fail
              //действие при неуспешной оплате
          },
          onComplete: function () { //Вызывается как только виджет получает от api.cloudpayments ответ с результатом транзакции.
              //например вызов вашей аналитики
          }
      }
  )
};
```

Вот так вызываю платежный виджет. При отправке формы он вызывается

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  if ( '946' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
    payPopup(); // - вызов платежки
  }
}, false );
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы все работало как мне надо?